# Characterization of a continuous function $f$ given properties on its derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Consider an absolutely continuous real function $f:[a,b]\to [0,1]$ and constants $d> c>0$. Assume the following:

- $f(a)=0$
- if $f(t)=0$ and $t$ is a point of differentiability, then $f'(t)=c>0$.
- if $f(t)>0$ and $t$ is a point of differentiability, then $f'(t)=-d>0$.

Is it true that $f(t)=0$ almost everywhere? If not, how can it be constructed?

Comment: Any continuous, everywhere non differentiable function, with range in $[0,1]$ and $f(a) = 0$, satisfies your assumptions.

Comment: @Rigel you're right, I forgot to say that it is absolutely continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists no such function.

If $t\in (a,b)$ is a differentiability point and $f(t) = 0$, then $t$ is a minimum point and then $f'(t) = 0$. So there cannot be such points.

Since $f$ is absolutely continuous, it is differentiable a.e. hence, by the previous point, we must have $f(t) > 0$ and $f'(t) = -d < 0$ at every point of differentiability.
But this is clearly impossible, since $f(x) = \int_a^x f'(t)\, dt$.